How do I get my tiny zero's wifi shield to connect with my telegram bot?
The code i am using is shown below. I keep getting an error message where it has failed to send out a test message to my telegram bot. how do i resolve this issue? (Im using the ATWINC1500 WiFi module)
screenshot of error message
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include <WiFiSSLClient.h>
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// WiFi credentials
char ssid[] = "ssid"; // Replace with your WiFi SSID
char pass[] = "password"; // Replace with your WiFi password

// Telegram bot credentials
#define BOT_TOKEN "token" // Replace with your bot token
#define CHAT_ID "chatid" // Replace with your chat ID

WiFiSSLClient client; // Secure client for HTTPS
UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOT_TOKEN, client); // Telegram bot instance

#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
#define SMI SerialUSB
#else
#define SMI Serial
#endif

void setup() {
  SMI.begin(9600);
  while (!SMI) {
    ; // Wait for Serial port to initialize
  }

  SMI.println("=== Starting Setup ===");


  // Configure pins for TinyZero
  WiFi.setPins(8, 2, A3, -1);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  SMI.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  int wifi_attempts = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && wifi_attempts < 10) {
    SMI.print(".");
    delay(5000);
    wifi_attempts++;
  }

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    SMI.println("WiFi connected!");
    printWiFiStatus();
  } else {
    SMI.println("Failed to connect to WiFi. Restarting...");
    while (true); // Halt if WiFi fails
  }

  // DNS Resolution Test
  IPAddress telegramIP;
  if (WiFi.hostByName("api.telegram.org", telegramIP)) {
    SMI.print("Telegram Server IP resolved: ");
    SMI.println(telegramIP);
  } else {
    SMI.println("Failed to resolve Telegram server address. Check DNS settings.");
    while (true);
  }

  // Send a test message to Telegram Bot
  SMI.println("Sending test message to Telegram Bot...");
  String message = "Hello from TinyZero!";
  if (bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, message, "")) {
    SMI.println("Message sent successfully!");
  } else {
    SMI.println("Failed to send message to Telegram Bot. Verify credentials and connection.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Example: Periodically send a test message every 30 seconds
  delay(30000);

  SMI.println("Sending periodic message to Telegram Bot...");
  String message = "This is a periodic message from TinyZero.";
  if (bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, message, "")) {
    SMI.println("Periodic message sent successfully!");
  } else {
    SMI.println("Failed to send periodic message to Telegram Bot. Verify credentials.");
  }
}

// Function to print WiFi connection details
void printWiFiStatus() {
  SMI.print("SSID: ");
  SMI.println(WiFi.SSID());

  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  SMI.print("IP Address: ");
  SMI.println(ip);

  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  SMI.print("Signal strength (RSSI): ");
  SMI.print(rssi);
  SMI.println(" dBm");
}

i have tried referring to online resources from arduino docs https://docs.arduino.cc/libraries/wifi101/#Server%20class, there should be a successful connection to telegram's api server through SSL
